# Change div width

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the width size of my `<div>` in javascript.
I am very new to HTML and javascript and I am having a hard time doing so because of it.

What I am doing is creating a progress bar for a game. 
I managed to get this working with `<progress>` but I want a bit more flexibility.

so I used this:

```
function botHealth(){
var meter = document.getElementsByClassName("meter")[0]; //If it's the first and only instance of 'meter'
var span = meter.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
span.style.width = "calc("+span.style.width+"% - 10%)"}
```

`<div class="meter">
    <span style="width: 25%"></span>
</div>`

I got the idea from this site [here](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/)

Comment: have you tried http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
var meter = document.getElementsByClassName("meter")[0]; //If it's the first and only instance of 'meter'
var span = meter.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

span.style.width = "50%";
```

If you wanted to calculate something, you could use the css `calc` function.

E.g:

```
span.style.width = "calc(50% + 15%)";
```

This however [isn't fully supported on older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

To take it away from itself, you can do this:

```
span.style.width = "calc("+span.style.width+"% + 20%)";
```

If you're calling a function, it should go like this:

(button is a made up variable that would be.. well a button)

```
button.onclick = function(){
  var new_width = span.style.width;

  new_width = "calc("+new_width+"% - 10%)";
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to subtract from `"100%"`? I'm asking because it seems to be a `String` and not a number.

Comment: `50%` would still be a number, that's just how javascript puts it into the style. @Tags

Comment: Or use `calc` function in `css` which I've updated answer for :) @Tags

Comment: I tride doing `span.style.width -= "10%";` but did not work. Is there a certain way it would be done to subtract each time by calling a method?

Comment: Youy could try this @Tags: `span.style.width = "calc("+span.style.width+"% - 10%)";`

Comment: It worked the first time but after the function was called again it stayed the same.

Comment: What is the function? Each function call you should set a variable to `span.style.width` and use that to take away. I'll update answer. @Tags

Comment: My function contains your code and the function is called everytime damage is done.

Answer (score 1):

Give your span a class, e.g. meterProgress, this is not necessary but it probably will be helpful anyway

```
<div class="meter">
    <span class="meterProgress"></span>
</div>
```

Now in javascript you need to find the span and change its width

```
var progressValue = 30;
var meterProgress = document.getElementsByClassName("meterProgress")[0];
meterProgress.style.width = progressValue.toString() + "%";
```

You could also use jquery as it helps with this kind of manipulation, then it would be as simple as (even without assigning a class to the span

```
var progressValue = 30;
$('.meter>span').css('width', progressValue.toString() + "%")
```